# Xslt transformation

Tags: xslt

I want to transform with xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<root>
<value1>test1</value1>
<value2>test2</value2>
<value3>test3</value3>
</root>
```

in :

```
<input type="hidden" value="test1" name="value1" />
<input type="hidden" value="test2" name="value2" />
<input type="hidden" value="test3" name="value3" />
```

What is the best way to do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this rule is semantically clear and sucint:

```
<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(),'value')]">
    <input type="hidden" value="{.}" name="{name()}" /> 
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Ah, yeah, I totally forgot about `starts-with`. I work with more than a few languages, I forget which ones have which string functions.

Comment: Another way to write the match pattern would be `match="root/*"`.

Comment: @Michael Kay: I agree. That would restrict the pattern to only the children of `root`.

Answer (score 1):

You XML's badly designed; if possible, instead of `<value1>` you should use `<value name="value1">` or something similar.

That having been said, you can do:

```
<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(),'value')]">
  <xsl:element name="input">
    <xsl:attribute name="type">hidden</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="value">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
     </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="name">
      <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

If you elements were `<value name="value1">` instead, the match becomes simply `match="value"`, which is much faster, and the name attribute becomes `<xsl:value-of select="@name">`.

Comment: NP; It's a bit more verbose than using the `{}` syntax for attributes, but personally I prefer this unless there's a compelling reason to do otherwise; There's no non-xsl elements in the stylesheet, making it clearer exactly what the output should be.